# Implementing a graph without a library in Python

Tags: python, graph, directed-graph, undirected-graph

I'm new to Python and trying to build a directed graph without the use of a library. Can someone please confirm if I'm understanding this example correctly?

```
from collections import defaultdict 
class Graph:
    def __init__(graph):
        graph.dict = defaultdict(list)
    def add(graph,node,adjacent_node): 
        graph.dict[node].append(adjacent_node)    #line 6
        graph.dict[adjacent_node].append(node)    #line 7

graph = Graph()
graph.add('1','2') 
graph.add('2','5') 
graph.add('2','3') 
graph.add('4','5') 
graph.add('4','3') 
graph.add('6','4') 
graph.add('6','5')
print('Dictionary:',graph.dict)

_____
Output:
Dictionary: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'1': ['2'], '2': ['1', '5', '3'], '5': ['2', '4', '6'], '3': ['2', '4'], '4': ['5', '3', '6'], '6': ['4', '5']})
```

From my understanding, this example is building an *undirected* graph

- on line 6, they're adding the path from the original node to the adjacent node
- on line 7, they're adding the path from the adjacent node BACK to the original node

Is this correct?

Also I'm a little confused if these are the nodes, why do they need the path to the next node? Wouldn't the edges take care of that once I create an addEdges function, or does this function suffice for both adding nodes and edges?

[example source](https://www.codespeedy.com/generate-a-graph-using-dictionary-in-python/)

Comment: Your understanding is correct up until the last paragraph. `add` already adds edges, along with nodes if they don't already exist. If you want a digraph (directed graph), remove line 7.

Comment: Got it thank you @ggorlen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an [*adjacency list*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) representation of a graph here.

In your current implementation, `add` creates an undirected edge from `node` to `adjacent_node`. "Undirected edge" means if you're at `node`, you can transition to `adjacent_node`, and if you're at `adjacent_node`, you can transition to `node`. That's a bidirectional relationship.

`add` also creates these nodes if they don't already exist thanks to the `defaultdict`. Think of nodes as keys in your dict, and edges as an element inside a list associated with a node.

If you want a directed graph, that means `add` should only create one edge from the source to the destination:

```
def add(graph,node,adjacent_node): 
    graph.dict[node].append(adjacent_node)
    # graph.dict[adjacent_node].append(node)  # <- skip if you want a directed graph
```

No more functions are necessary to add here to represent a graph.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation clears a lot up. I'm referring to this example for a project I'm working on and the data is unordered so I think this will work.

Comment: Will do thanks! Additionally, would you say that using an adjacency matrix would be a better approach for a directed graph? The wiki page you referenced mentions it as an alternative to adjacency lists.

Comment: There are many ways to represent graphs, and it's application-dependent so neither is objectively better for a directed graph on all use cases. See [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218322/what-is-better-adjacency-lists-or-adjacency-matrices-for-graph-problems-in-c) [2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/79322/when-are-adjacency-lists-or-matrices-the-better-choice) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625618/graphs-representation-adjacency-list-vs-matrix) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725723/adjacency-matrix-vs-adjacency-list-for-directed-weighted-graph)